# Is there a way of using FPDF to generate a PDF file from forms in Django?

Tags: python, django, pdf-generation

I am trying to generate a PDF file and give it a custom name using Django 4.0.2 I have 2 inputs, one for the name and one for the photos, I want to be able to generate the PDF without saving it in my database but return it back to the user. I am using no models for this, plain html and python.
I have the inputs:

```
<input
                    type="text"
                    id="inputPassword6"
                    class="form-control"
                    aria-describedby="passwordHelpInline"
                    name="name"
                />
<input
                    class="form-control"
                    type="file"
                    id="formFileMultiple"
                    multiple
                    accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg"
                    name="photos"
                />
        <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-3">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save PDF</button>
        </div>
```

And I am trying to merge and return the PDF file like this:

```
    if request.method == "POST" or "FILES":
        name = request.POST["name"]
        photos = request.FILES["photos"]

        # Convert photos to PDF
        pdf = FPDF()
        # imagelist is the list with all image filenames
        for image in photos:
            pdf.add_page()
            pdf.image(image, 0,0,210,297)
        pdf.output(f"{name} AIA 114.pdf", "F")
```

Current error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'
```

It looks like FPDF can not look into the image I provided. I tried to decode the image, but I hit another error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Can someone help me solve this problem or propose another way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that did work for me using no models is below, however this is hardcoded because I found out later, that I could have used `default_storage` and `ContentFile` inbuilt in django because the files are already in memory (`InMemoryFile`).

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'index.html')

    if request.method == "POST" or "FILES":
        try:
            # Get data from inputs
            name = request.POST["name"]
            photos = request.FILES.getlist('photos')

            count = 1
            if (len(photos) > 1):
                # For multiple photos
                imglist = []
                counter = 0

                # Write buffers and append to the list
                for photo in photos:
                    bytes = photo.read() # Read files in memory
                    path = django_settings.MEDIA_ROOT + f"buffer{counter}.png" # auto path
                    counter = counter + 1 # counter
                    file = open(path, 'wb')
                    file.write(bytes)
                    file.close()
                    imglist.append(file)

                # CONVERT
                listconv = []
                counter = 0
                for img in imglist:
                    path = django_settings.MEDIA_ROOT + f"buffer{counter}.png"
                    img = Image.open(path)
                    img = img.convert('RGB')
                    listconv.append(img)
                    counter=counter+1
                img.save(django_settings.MEDIA_ROOT + f"{name}.pdf", save_all=True, append_images=listconv[:-1])

                # Return response
                img = open(django_settings.MEDIA_ROOT + f"{name}.pdf", 'rb')
                response = FileResponse(img)
                return response

            elif (len(photos) == 1):
                # For single photo
                photos = request.FILES["photos"]
                # WRITE FILE
                bytes = photos.read() # CONTENT UPLOADED FILE
                path = django_settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "buffer"
                file=open(path,'wb')
                file.write(bytes)
                file.close()

                # CONVERT
                image1 = Image.open(path)
                im1 = image1.convert('RGB')
                im1.save(django_settings.MEDIA_ROOT + f"{name}.pdf")
                img = open(django_settings.MEDIA_ROOT + f"{name}.pdf", 'rb')
                # Return response
                response = FileResponse(img)
                return response
            else:
                print("ERROR")
        except UnidentifiedImageError:
            return render(request, 'error.html')
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's great to see that you were able to find the answer to the initial question. Could you perhaps edit it to remove all the code specific to your use case to focus on the exact part that solved your original issue? This might help others who find themselves in a similar situation to understand your solution better.